# Variable referencing for an ndb.Model to be used in query

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

I have the following code in my app:

```
query_string = Booking.query()
```

Which I would like to substitute `Booking` (an `ndb.Model` class) based on some conditional logic.

I am uncertain how to create a new `Booking` or other `ndb.Model`'s query object "on the fly".

**My pseudo code:**

```
my_query_object = ndb.Model('Booking').query()
```

Is this the correct approach or can I start with a generic `ndb.Model` query and specify the type via text further along in the query building process?

Answer (score 2):

OK, as what happens, posting a question often prompts the RTFM angel to my savior.

From the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#constructor):

> Typically, an application creates a Query by calling Model.query().
>   But it's also possible to call ndb.Query().
>
> Arguments
>
> kind Optional kind string. Normally, the name of a entity class.

So the solution code for my example becomes:

```
query_string = ndb.Query(kind='Booking')
```